# Implementar botón con cuenta regresiva de forma persistente hasta terminar la cuenta atrás aunque el usuario cierre la aplicación del segundo plano

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase, firestore

No se que método o forma emplear para que un botón con una cuenta regresiva relativamente larga (digamos 8 horas) mantenga la cuenta atrás aunque un usuario cierre la aplicación.

Implemente el uso de un servicio pero cuando se cierra la aplicación del segundo plano pierdo la cuenta atrás iniciada al pulsar el botón. Si alguno podéis recomendarme algo para resolver el problema me ayudaría mucho, no se de la existencia de nada que me sirva para ello pero veo aplicaciones donde se implementa y funciona

Entiendo que debería de almacenarse el dato de cuando se pulsa en una base de datos y hacer una cuenta del tiempo transcurrido con el dato almacenado en la base de datos

Estoy usando firebase como base de datos para guardar el perfil de usuario y los puntos que va almacenando en la app pero no se como usar el timestamp que es como se me ocurre que debería de guardar el dato de la fecha

Necesito algo de ayuda para saber que camino tomar en la resolución de este problema que no se como solventar

```
binding.spinwheel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), SpinnerActivity.class));

            // sacamos la hora minuto segundo y dia en el que se pulsa el boton del spinweel
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss", Locale.CANADA);
            Date now = new Date();
            String hourPulse = formatter.format(now);

            // hacer visible el spinweelTime
            binding.spinwheelTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // implementamos el contador
            new CountDownTimer(3000000,1000){
                @Override
                final public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


                    int second = (int) (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60 ;
                    int minute = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000*60)) % 60);
                    int hour   = (int) ((millisUntilFinished / (1000*60*60)) % 24);

                    binding.spinwheelTime.setText(""+hour+":"+minute+":"+second );
                    binding.spinwheelTime.setEnabled(false);
                    binding.spinwheel.setEnabled(false);


                }
```

Estoy usando SimpleDateFormat y Date para crear el formato de fecha y sacar la hora para guardarla en una varible pero no se como usar ese dato ( hourPulse) para hacer que "new CountDownTimer(3000000,1000)" cambie acorde a la informacion que me da el SimpleDateFormat y Date

Comment: Es correcto. Guarda la fecha de inicio e inicias el contador (Para que se vea más bonito). Cuando vuelvan a abrir la app busca ese dato y ejecuta de nuevo el contador con la fecha de inicio ya guardada, lamentablemente no puedo decirte como hacerlo en Java.

Comment: comparte algo de codigo

Comment: acabo de compartir el código gracias por la atención y perdonar mi torpeza soy muy nuevo en esto